# Angular - how to dynamically filter out objects comparing 2 arrays?

Tags: angular, filter, observable

I have an array of objects that I get from the API with an

```
observable: 
[{id: x, name: xx, age: yy}, {.....}, ...]
```

Then what I do is to map these objects to my custom module (a search box), so you can input strings and search for a specific object.

This search box also provides the last 5 object selected, and I'm having issue with this.

To have the last 5 selected objects, I created a `behaviourSubject` where I push the objects:

```
this.recentlyUsedObjects.push(_.find(this.objects, c => this.selectedObject === c.id.toString()));
      this.recentlyUsedObjects= this.recentlyUsedObjects.filter(c => c !== undefined);
      if (this.recentlyUsedObjects.length > 5) this.recentlyUsedObjects.shift();
```

so `this.recentlyUsedObjects` is my BehaviourSubject,

`this.objects` is the array in which I store the list of objects I get from the subscription in the `ngOnInit()`,

`this.selectedObject` this is the string where I store the currently selected object from my search box

`if (this.recentlyUsedObjects.length > 5) this.recentlyUsedObjects.shift();` with this line, I make the array always be of 5 elements, as I want to show only the last 5 clicked objects,

```
this.recentlyUsedObjects= this.recentlyUsedObjects.filter(c => c !== undefined);
```

meanwhile this line was needed because I had an issue, when the App is loaded, the recent object list is empty, so I was getting an error as it was trying to map values from an `undefined object`, what I did to solve it, it's as soon as one object is pushed into this array, I filter out the initial undefined Object, as I saw that with `push()` it just appends the new object and I still have in `position[0]` the `undefined object`.

so the last step, in the `ngOnInit`, I need to filter out the main object list using my `recentlyUsedObjects` array, so in the App it shows the last 5 objects BUT it doesn't repeat those objects in the below list, where ALL the objects are.

So if an object goes to the `recentlyUsedObjects` list, it doesn't need to show in the `allObjects` list.

My issue is, the filtering out works, but what doesn't work is, when more than 5 objects have been selected, the `this.recentlyUsedObjects` will start to push out the last element, to keep the array always at 5, what doesn't happen is, once an object is pushed out, it should go back to be displayed in the `allObjects` list, but this doesn't happen!

How can I change my filtering function to keep checking if an object is not in the `recentlyUsedObjects` list anymore and put it back in the original list?

```
this.objectService.getObjects().subscribe(obj=> {
      this.getRecentObjects().subscribe(recent=> {
        this.objects = obj;
        obj = obj.filter(o => {
          return !_.find(recent, r => {
            return r.id === o.id;
          });
        });
```

`this.getRecentObjects()` this is the BehaviourSubject I was talking above, in which the `this.recentlyUsedObjects` are send with `next()`;

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

so after some tries apparently the code was correct, with that filter I should have had objects returning to the original array after they have been pushed out of the 5object recent array.

the change I made was:

```
this.objectService.getObjects().subscribe(obj=> {
      this.getRecentObjects().subscribe(recent=> {
        this.objects = obj;
        obj = obj.filter(o => {
          return !_.find(recent, r => {
            return r.id === o.id;
          });
        });
```

here > `this.objects = obj;`

I changed it to : `this.objects = _.cloneDeep(obj);`

and instead of doing: `obj = obj.filter(o => { ...`

I do:

```
this.objects = this.objects.filter(o => { ...
```

not really sure why this works and the one before doesn't, but at least now it works